# Website html links printed in Excel have odd gaps

Tags: html, excel, vba

Edit: Thank you Zwenn for the help.

The problem I have with the code below is that the html links printed have cell gaps of 12-13 spaces printed vertically in excel, I would like to avoid having spaces between between the texts. I suspect having used the wrong elements and class names when directing it to search the href html links and the code goes through other unnecessary items, creating the additional gaps. I need help in solving the issue with the elements and items I set up.

The printed html is found under "notStrikeout" class names, found within the 6th and 7th sub-classes. Website in question "https://www.racingandsports.com/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/ballarat/2021-08-29/R1".

```
Sub Horse5()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument


Dim node As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeTr As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeDiv As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim Element1 As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim node1 As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim currentUrl As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/ballarat/2021-08-29/R1", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

Elements found here.

```
With html.getElementsByClassName("table")
For Each node In html.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs table-responsive marginTop fgr-table-lvl-1")
    r = r + 1: c = 4
    For Each nodeTr In node.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        With nodeTr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            If .Length Then
            
            ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 6) = .Item(6).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 7) = .Item(7).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            On Error Resume Next

            r = r + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next
End With

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "input complete"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the hell are you using the same VBA code as the basis for which I wrote you [in the last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906090/finding-webpage-elements-to-print-on-excel-spreadsheet-using-vba/68909563#68909563) that it is not good? You don't use IE. You can throw out **everything** about it without checking.

The use of `On Error Resume Next` is only used when there is no other way. This is **only** the case when you **cannot know** what the check for a result or the presence of an object will result in.

You pass over all errors. Therefore, you cannot determine where your error lies. You obviously lack the experience to see it  without error message. That is not bad, you can gain the needed experience. If you had omitted `On Error Resume Next` (and twice it is not necessary anyway, as I wrote last time), you would have received an error message from which you could have worked your way forward.

I will now show you the *"bad"* way using `On Error Resume Next`. If you use this, then **only around the lines of code in which an error is expected to occur** (that you wish to ignore). Afterwards, you should switch on the error handling again in any case. This can be done with `On Error GoTo 0`. Whenever you use this, you must then check whether the case you expect has occurred or not. You want to know whether a link was entered or not. So you have to check whether there is something in the corresponding cell. Only if there is, do you count up the current number of rows.

One more thing. Declare all variables and don't declare variables you don't need. Write `Option Explicit` as first line in every module outside any other VBA code. That will generate compile errors for undeclared variables. This is for good programming style and especially to prevent typos in variable names.

```
Sub Horse5()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim node As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeTr As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  r = 1
  c = 4
  
  With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.racingandsports.com/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/ballarat/2021-08-29/R1", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
  End With
  
  For Each node In html.getElementsByClassName("hidden-xs table-responsive marginTop fgr-table-lvl-1")
    For Each nodeTr In node.getElementsByTagName("tr")
      With nodeTr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If .Length Then
          On Error Resume Next
          ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 6) = .Item(6).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
          ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 7) = .Item(7).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
          On Error GoTo 0
          If ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 6) <> "" Then
            r = r + 1
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
  
  MsgBox "input complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: `only around the lines of code in which an error can occur`  - suggest amend `only around the lines where an error is **expected** to occur <that you wish to ignore>.`